# How to add admin custom field using a method

Tags: django, django-admin

I'm following the example in Django admin site list_display custom method and I'm getting an error 'colored_name() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)', what is the issue?

```
class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    color_code = models.CharField(max_length=6)

def colored_name(self):
    return format_html(
        '<span style="color: #{};">{} {}</span>',
        self.color_code,
        self.first_name,
        self.last_name,
    )

class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'colored_name')
```

Comment: What's your admin code for `Person`?

Comment: Never post your code in comment section, please modify your question with the relevant code. Can you also share the traceback please?

Comment: Please post the full traceback and fix your code indentation.

Comment: thanks @shang/alasdair for improving my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define `colored_name` inside `PersonAdmin class` not `Person Model`, because it's a method used for the admin panel. Also, it receives an `obj` argument representing the `person` instance.

```
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'colored_name')

    def colored_name(self, obj):
        return format_html(
            '<span style="color: #{};">{} {}</span>',
            obj.color_code,
            obj.first_name,
            obj.last_name,
         )
```